# Selecting values present in one column but not in all other columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Suppose I have columns `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4` in `myTable` and I need to print out **the values  exclusive  to only one column**  .

So if the above looks like

```
  col1    col2    col3    col4
  s        e       c        b 
  c        c       a        s
  n        s       e        a
  d        d       q        c
```

Then the output should be **n, q b** since they are exclusive only to `col1`, `col3` and `col4` respectively.

How can I achieve this through a query in mysql php?

**EDIT** The duplicates **dont have to be in a single row** .I have changed the the table layout now to make it clear.

Comment: i'm sure there's some real data not just letters - and yes it does matter what that is.

Comment: All of your duplicates are duplicated within a single row.  If there were an 'n' in col2, col3, or col4 in a *different* row, would that remove it from your desired results?

Comment: yes, they don't have to be in a single row. Sorry about the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a SQL-only solution, you can do a query per column like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    col1 AS unique_on_col1
FROM table
WHERE     col1 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM table)
      AND col1 NOT IN (SELECT col3 FROM table)
      AND col1 NOT IN (SELECT col4 FROM table)
```

It's possible to combine all four queries with `UNION` but that may not be necessary depending on what you want to do with the data. Also, this query should not perform very well with large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

One slightly more compact way of getting all of them at once:

```
select distinct col1 
  from myTable 
 where col1 not in (select a.col1 
                     from myTable a join myTable b 
                       on a.col1 = b.col2 or a.col1=b.col3 or a.col1=b.col4)
 union
select distinct col2 
  from myTable 
 where col2 not in (select a.col2 
                     from myTable a join myTable b 
                       on a.col2 = b.col1 or a.col2=b.col3 or a.col2=b.col4)
 union
select distinct col3 
  from myTable 
 where col3 not in (select a.col3 
                     from myTable a join myTable b 
                       on a.col3 = b.col1 or a.col3=b.col2 or a.col3=b.col4)
 union
select distinct col4 
  from myTable 
 where col4 not in (select a.col4 
                     from myTable a join myTable b 
                       on a.col4 = b.col1 or a.col4=b.col2 or a.col4=b.col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "
    SELECT DISTINCT 'col1' as descr,col1 as val FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 'col2' as descr,col2 as val FROM myTable
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT 'col3' as descr,year as val FROM myTable";

$result = @mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $make_array[$row['descr']][]=$row['val'];
}
```

I'm guessing this should work. Dint try the code out but give this one a shot and let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT col1 AS unique_on_col1
FROM table
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col2 FROM table)
  AND col1 NOT IN (SELECT col3 FROM table)
  AND col1 NOT IN (SELECT col4 FROM table)
```